# What are the implications of using base 40 to encode a String?

Tags: java, compression, redis, base64, base32

I've seen it suggested that Base 40 encoding can be used to compress Strings (in Java to send to a Redis instance FWIW) and a quick test shows it more efficient for some of the data I'm using than an alternative I'm considering; Smaz.

Is there any reason to prefer base 32 or 64 encoding over 40? Any disadvantage, is encoding like this potentially lossless?

Answer (score 1):

40 provides letters (probably lower case unless your application tends to use upper case most of the time) and digits for 36, and then four more for punctuation and shifts.  You can make it lossless by making one of the remaining an escape so the next one or two characters represent a byte not in the other 39.  Also a good approach is to have a shift-lock character that toggles between upper and lower case, if you tend to have strings of upper case characters.

40 is a convenient base, since three base-40 digits fit nicely in two bytes.  40^3 (64000) is a smidge less than 2^16 (65536).

What you should use depends on the statistics of your data.